# Error comes while linking firebase with my project through node js file in flutter

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

An anonymous error in my 'logs' section came on firebase project, while no error was shown on 'run' in Android studio. I don't know anything about node js, i just wanted to link my app through it, that's why i am forced to use it, can someone help me please.
Here's the complete error on firebase project -> Functions -> logs

```
srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/collection-group.js:54
    async *getPartitions(desiredPartitionCount) {
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:39:28)
```

Here's the second error on firebase's project -> functions -> logs. :

```
Error detected in onCreateFollower {"errorEvent":{"eventTime":"2020-10-31T06:41:42.682Z","message":"/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/collection-group.js:54\n    async *getPartitions(desiredPartitionCount) {\n          ^\n\nSyntaxError: Unexpected token *\n    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)\n    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)\n    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)\n    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)\n    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:39:28)","serviceContext":{"service":"onCreateFollower","resourceType":"cloud_function"}},"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.clouderrorreporting.v1beta1.Insight","errorGroup":"COvaxM_ErLfhbg"
```

Here's the code in Android Studio on index.js file -

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//   functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
//   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

exports.onCreateFollower = functions.firestore.document("/followers/{userId}/userFollowers/{followerId}").onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  console.log('Follower Created', snapshot.id);
  const userId = context.params.userId;
  const followerId = context.params.followerId;
  const followedUserPostsRef = admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(userId).collection('userPosts');
  const timelinePostsRef = admin.firestore().collection('timeline').doc(followerId).collection('timelinePosts');
  const querySnapshot = await followedUserPostsRef.get();
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    if(doc.exists) {
       const postId = doc.id;
       const postData = doc.data();
       timelinePostsRef.doc(postId).set(postData);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: what is yout function Node version, firebase admin version, firebase functions version? check yout package.json for these information.

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi I have set node version to 8(By default, it was 12) firebase admin version is 9.2.0  and firebase functions' versioj is - 3.11.0, estLint - 5.12.0,  eslint-plugin-promise is 4.0.1, firebase-functions-test is 0.2.0

Comment: Node 8 for firebase functions is about to be deprecated. Try Node 10 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this "firebase-admin": "^8.13.0","firebase-functions": "^3.6.1". This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change the version of firebase-admin to "firebase-admin": "^ 8.10.0" and firebase-functions to "firebase-functions": "^ 3.6.1". I also had this problem and solved it.